# listen for completed URL change in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension's background script, I can use

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function
  (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log(changeInfo);
  }
);
```

to listen to page updates. The variable `changeInfo` will typically be something of

```js
{status: "loading", url: "https://new.url/path"}
{status: "complete"}
{favIconUrl: "https://assets.new.url/path/to/favicon.svg"}
{status: "loading"}
{status: "complete"}
{title: "New page title"}
```

I would like to know when a URL change has *completed*, but is seems that the `"complete"` statuses don't contain the info what actually has completed.

Any hints?

Comment: There's no such thing as "URL change has completed" because this change is instantaneous. The `status: 'complete'` change refers to the page loading status and corresponds to `load` event inside that tab. Note that you can use `tab` object to read the current properties.

Comment: So the two `loading`/`complete` don't necessarily correspond to content load and favicon load?

Comment: It depends on all the resources. Visually it's the "loading" animation in the tab favicon.